# downloading an unknown type of image to temp and sending to browser with finding content type using magic numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

**Subject:**

I'm coming from nodejs so using some examples from nodejs to get the concept across.

1. **Temp Directory:** I'm using dotnet core so the app can run on either mac, windows or linux and the confusion lies for temp directory across operating systems where this image will be downloaded. (find temp dir in nodejs on any os -> `os.tmpDir()`)
2. **File format unknown:** file format is unknown, not necessary to know in order to download the image and save but is necessary when sending it to the browsers in headers and it can be done using magic numbers. [Reference](https://asecuritysite.com/forensics/magic)

**Download Image from Web**

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) 
{
    byte [] data = webClient.DownloadData("https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10555140_10201501435212873_1318258071_n.jpg?oh=97ebc03895b7acee9aebbde7d6b002bf&oe=53C9ABB0&__gda__=1405685729_110e04e71d9");

   using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data)) 
   {
       using (var yourImage = Image.FromStream(mem)) 
       { 
          // how to save in the temp directory for all operating systems 
       }
   } 

}
```

**Send the image to browser**

```
byte[] ar;
using(FileStream fstream = new FileStream(tempPathForImage, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);)
{
    ar = new byte[(long)fstream.Length];
    fstream.read(ar, 0, fstream.Length);
}

sw.WriteLine("Content-Type: "); // image/jpeg unknown, check first 4 bytes
sw.WriteLine("Content-Length: {0}", ar.Length); //Let's 
sw.WriteLine(); 
sw.BaseStream.Write(ar, 0, ar.Length);
```

**Magic Numbers:**

magic numbers are basically first 4 bytes of a file that can help to find out the file type/extension. I've done something similar in nodejs where as image right before it gets streamed, i get a chance to read the first four bytes and then i set the header (content type) and continue streaming there. It's important to set the header before an image starts streaming, that's why you see in the following code checks for `writeStream == null`

```
response.on('data', function(chunk){
    if(writeStream == null) {
        url += '.' + getExtension(chunk.toString('hex', 0, 4));
        writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(url);
        writeStream.on('error', reject);
        writeStream.on('finish', function(){
            data.file = url;
            resolve(data);
        });
    }
    writeStream.write(chunk);
});
```

Some file formats and their magic numbers.

```
"ffd8ffDB": "jpg",
"ffd8ffe0": "jpg",
"ffd8ffe1": "jpg",
"ffd8ffe2": "jpg",
"ffd8ffe3": "jpg",
"ffd8ffe8": "jpg",
"ffd8ffdb": "jpg",
"89504e47": "png",
"47494638": "gif",
```

**Question**

1. Solve the problem of finding the temp directory
2. How to read first four bytes during the phase of streaming but just before sending, set the headers for content type (for once) and continue streaming.

Comment: [`Path.GetTempPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettemppath?view=netframework-4.7#System_IO_Path_GetTempPath). You may also consider using [App_Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579229/app-data-directory-in-asp-net5-mvc6). For detecting magic numbers in streams, can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: thanks, for intercepting as image is streaming, can't wrap my head around in c#, I've a vague idea of extending and overriding some method responsible for streaming.

Comment: `byte[] firstFour = new byte[4]; getExtension(fstream.read(ar, 0, 4])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a specialized stream that wraps another stream, then override `Read()` to handle that detection. Here's a starting point. Most of this is boilerplate that defers to the wrapped stream.

```
class ImageDetectionStream : Stream
{
    public string Mime { get; private set; }

    private readonly Stream _stream;
    private readonly byte[] _consideredBytes = new byte[MaxMagicNumberSize];
    private int _consideredPosition;

    private static readonly IDictionary<byte[], string> Magics = new Dictionary<byte[], string>
    {
        [new byte[] { 0xff, 0xdb, 0xff, 0xdb }] = "image/jpeg",
        [new byte[] { 0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe0 }] = "image/jpeg",
        [new byte[] { 0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe1 }] = "image/jpeg",
        // and so on... 
    };

    private static readonly int MaxMagicNumberSize = Magics.Keys.Max(x => x.Length);

    public ImageDetectionStream(Stream stream)
    {
        _stream = stream ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stream));
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var value = _stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        if (Mime != null) return value;

        Array.Copy(buffer, 0, _consideredBytes, 0, _consideredBytes.Length);
        _consideredPosition += value;

        if (_consideredPosition < MaxMagicNumberSize) return value;

        foreach (var magic in Magics)
        {
            var possibleMagic = buffer.Take(magic.Key.Length).ToArray();
            if (possibleMagic.SequenceEqual(magic.Key))
            {
                Mime = magic.Value;
                break;
            }
        }

        return value;
    }

    // boilerplate

    public override void Flush()
    {
        _stream.Flush();
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return _stream.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        _stream.SetLength(value);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _stream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override bool CanRead => _stream.CanRead;

    public override bool CanSeek => _stream.CanSeek;

    public override bool CanWrite => _stream.CanWrite;

    public override long Length => _stream.Length;

    public override long Position
    {
        get => _stream.Position;
        set => _stream.Position = value;
    }
}
```

Example use -

```
using (var fs = File.OpenRead("\\path\\to\\image\\file"))
using (var imageStream = new ImageDetectionStream(fs))
{
    var bytes = new byte[128];
    var bytesRead = imageStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    Console.WriteLine($"Image has {imageStream.Mime} type.");
}
```

Outputs:

> Image has image/jpeg type.